# Cursor index out of bounds in Android app

Tags: android, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to use tu putExtras() method :

MyLocation.java :

```
Intent detailsTerrain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsTerrain.class);
detailsTerrain.putExtra("AdresseKey", realAdresse);
detailsTerrain.putExtra("NomDuTerrainKey", nomParc);
startActivity(detailsTerrain);
```

Where realAdresse and nomParc are variables in TextBoxs that I get when I click on.

DetailsTerrains.java :

```
MySQLLite db = new MySQLLite(this);
Intent i = getIntent();
String adresse = i.getStringExtra("AdresseKey");
String nomDuTerrain = i.getStringExtra("NomDuTerrainKey");
String ville = db.getAdresseTerrain(nomDuTerrain);
```

MySQLLite.java :

```
public String getAdresseTerrain(String nom){
    System.out.println(nom);
    String adresseDuTerrain;

    // 1. get reference to readable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // 2. build query
    Cursor cursor =
            db.query(TABLE_TERRAINS, // a. table
                    COLUMNS, // b. column names
                    " NOM = ?", // c. selections
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(nom) }, // d. selections args
                    null, // e. group by
                    null, // f. having
                    null, // g. order by
                    null); // h. limit

    // 3. if we got results get the first one
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    // 4. build book object
    TerrainDatabase terrain = new TerrainDatabase();
    terrain.setPositionMap(cursor.getString(6));
    terrain.setDepartement(cursor.getInt(4));

    adresseDuTerrain = terrain.getPositionMap();

    return adresseDuTerrain;
}
```

But it's not working, I have the following message :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.roses.myplayground/com.example.roses.myplayground.DetailsTerrain}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

In the SecondActivity.java, if I replace :

```
String ville = db.getAdresseTerrain(nomDuTerrain);
```

With :

```
String ville = db.getAdresseTerrain("Rucker Park");
```

Then it works..
So, first I decide to check what is in my nomDuTerrain variable with Log.d
When I try :

```
Log.d("Nom du terrain", nomDuTerrain);
```

I get something like "Rucker Park"...So I get the good value.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't see where you are instantiating your `Cursor`.

Comment: Can you show some code, please?